# Two-way link to the properties of all SelectedItems of a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection of objects. Next to that I have a bunch of TextBoxes and ComboBoxes that are TwoWay bound to the properties of the SelectedItem of that ListView. The items in my ListView have INotifyPropertyChanged. With that the user can select an item out of the ListView and edit the properties of it.

However editing a lot of items takes long, so I wanted to user to be able to select multiple items and edit the properties of all the selected items at once using the controls next to the ListView.

I already tried changing the DataContext to the SelectedItems property of the ListView, but that didn't work.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Edit:
To clarify, when the user selects more than one item, I want the editing controls next to the ListView to show nothing and then only when the user changes something in those controls the changes go to all the SelectedItems and the change stays visible in the TextBox or ComboBox because then the property is the same in all SelectedItems.

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="EditPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LayersList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanVerticallyScroll="True">
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FFD6D6D6" Margin="0,10,0,0"><Run Text="Name:"/></TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedNameBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFD6D6D6" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FFD6D6D6" Margin="0,10,0,0"><Run Text="Hitsound info:"/></TextBlock>
    <ComboBox x:Name="SelectedSampleSetBox" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding SampleSetString, Mode=TwoWay}" Cursor="Hand">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Soft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Drum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="SelectedHitsoundBox" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding HitsoundString, Mode=TwoWay}" Cursor="Hand">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Whistle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Finish" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Clap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </ComboBox>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: When you select multiple items, where do you want the relavant data to appear? Since you don't know how many the user would select, you'd want to add multiple controls dynamically.

Comment: One option would be to display the list in an editable DataGrid (or even a customized ListView), so you can edit items in place.

Comment: @Sach I edited the question for some further clarification.

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using data bindings for the editing controls. Instead I explicitly update them on a SelectionChangedEvent of the ListView. In there it also describes the logic for how it displays multiple selected items at once.

```
suppressEvents = true;

if (selectedLayers.TrueForAll(o => o.Name == selectedLayer.Name)) {
    SelectedNameBox.Text = selectedLayer.Name;
} else {
    SelectedNameBox.Text = "";
}
...

suppressEvents = false;
```

Then the ChangedEvents of the editing controls update all the SelectedItems.

```
private void SelectedNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (suppressEvents) return;

    string t = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    foreach (HitsoundLayer hitsoundLayer in LayersList.SelectedItems) {
        hitsoundLayer.Name = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you described the problem, it appears that you haven't thought this through.

If you have one list, and a bunch of controls which display the selected item's properties, where do you want the property data to be displayed when multiple items are selected? For example if you have a `Person` class like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When the user selects two different `Person` instances from the list, do you want the Text Box assigned to `Name` property to display all selected names? If not, if you want them in different text boxes, then you'd have to dynamically create as many text boxes as the items user selected. Either of which, I feel, may not be an ideal solution.

Here's an alternate solution; you display your data in a `DataGrid`.
I've used the simplest `DataGrid` here with `AutoGeneratingColumns` enabled.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Margin="4"
          Name="DataGridPersons"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>
```

Then, in your Code Behind (ideally you would use the `MVVM` patter and in that case in your `ViewModel`) you simply populate your data list.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        new Person() { Name = "Jane", City = "NY", Age = 23 },
        new Person() { Name = "Chelsea", City = "LA", Age = 27 },
        new Person() { Name = "Chris", City = "Chicago", Age = 25 }
    };

    DataContext = this;
}
```

By default the `DataGrid` is editable, and will record the changes you make.

Editable `DataGrid`:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

After OP's edited question, this is a new answer.

In that case, I'd get rid of the `SelectedItem`, and instead have different `string` properties corresponding to each property in your class object.

Assume your `Person` class is this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'd have the `ObservableCollection` and as many `string` properties as you have properties in your class; two in this instance.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

private string _editName = null;
public string EditName
{
    get { return _editName; }
    set
    {
        _editName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EditName");
    }
}

private string _editCity = null;
public string EditCity
{
    get { return _editCity; }
    set
    {
        _editCity = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EditCity");
    }
}
```

Then I'd bind text boxes to those properties:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
             Margin="8" Name="ItemListBox"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="8" Name="TxtName"
             TextChanged="TxtName_TextChanged"
             Text="{Binding EditName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
             Margin="8" Name="TxtCity"
             TextChanged="TxtCity_TextChanged"
             Text="{Binding EditCity, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the `TextChanged` event of each text box, I'd update your `ObservableCollection`.

```
private void TxtName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var person in Persons)
    {
        person.Name = EditName;
    }
}

private void TxtCity_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var person in Persons)
    {
        person.City = EditCity;
    }
}
```